# The different between おい and こら

Tags: interjections

What is the different between おい and こら? (Interjections)

Answer (score 1):

おい is a rude term of address for a person. こら is used when he scolds someone. おいこら is a very offensive word and it is often used when he picks a fight with a person. おーい is a term of address for a person or people in the distance.